# ImageViewからBitmapを取得する

Tags: android, bitmap

`ImageView`から`Bitmap`を取得しようとして下記のコードを書いたのですが、`ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_coupon)`の行で`NullPointerException`が返ってきます。どこが間違っているのでしょうか？
どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
    private Bitmap imageForScale;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_coupon); {
             imageForScale = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        }
    }
}
```

---追記---

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/touch_screen">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_coupon"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/coupon"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="240dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`activity_main.xml`に`imageView_coupon`というIDの`ImageView`が無いからだと思います。

追記

なるほど。そうすると、例外が出ているという行が間違っていますね。
そのしたの行で出ているはずです。

ImageViewの画像になにもないため`imageView.getDrawable()`がnullになり、nullなオブジェクトの`getBitmap()`を呼び出しているので例外が出ています。
ImageViewに画像を設定するには`src`で指定します。（`background`は背景です）

```
android:background="@drawable/coupon"
```

を

```
android:src="@drawable/coupon"
```

に変更してください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。activity_main.xmlを確認したところ、imageView_couponがありました。質問文にactivity_main.xmlを追記しました。

Comment: ImageViewの画像指定をsrcに変えると正常に動作しました！今までImageViewはほとんどbackgroundで指定していたと思うので気をつけようと思います。誠にありがとうございました。